# Как в laravel сделать preload шрифта?

Tags: laravel, webpack, шрифты

Как в laravel сделать preload шрифта? Google speed меня ругает за то, что я не делаю preload шрифтам.
JS и css у меня собирается так:

const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/some.js', 'public/js').sass('resources/sass/some.sass', 'public/css');

У шрифтов в css появляется hash типа: fonts/YandexSansDisplay-Bold.woff2?f502192c0c4f8b5ba5cfa259149ccbe7.

Однако, эти шрифты не попадают mix.json и я не могу сделать для них preload в blade шаблоне с помощью {{mix('path')}}.

Я пробовал добавлять шрифтам версии явно с помощью version(), но шрифты, которые генерируются в css не совпадают с теми, которым я явно прописал версию.

Как мне сделать preload для шрифта?

Что-то типа такого, но чтобы при этом подгружался шрифт, который используется в css
link rel="preload" href="{{mix('fonts/font.woof2')}}" as="script"

[image: Google speed ругается на preload шрифтов]